# Split list based on capitalization of constituent words

Tags: python, list, cpu-word

How to split a list ( of words ) based on the capitalization of the word. Usage of a single for loop would be preferred.

**Input string :**

```
"Capitalized words Get Listed first"
```

**Expected outcome:**

This should be split up in two separate lists `upper` and `lower` containing the Upper Case Words and lower case words respectively.

For example:
    upper = ["Capitalized", "Get", "Listed"]
    lower = ["words", "first"]

The final output must be displayed using these two lists and a single for loop :

**Expected Final output in display :**

```
Capitalized
Get
Listed
words
first
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the sentence into words, then sort. Capital letters will sort before lower case.

```
l = "Capitalized words Get Listed first"
sortedList = sorted(l.split())

lowerList = []
upperList = []
for word in sortedList:
    if word.istitle():
        upperList.append(word)
    else:
        lowerList.append(word)

upperList
['Capitalized', 'Get', 'Listed']

lowerList
['first', 'words']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little messy, but it works. It uses @Cyber's answer and then takes it a step further for the extra details.

```
l = "Capitalized words Get Listed first"
sorted_list = sorted(l.split())
lowercase = []
capitalized = []
for word in sorted_list:
    if word.capitalize() == word:
        capitalized.append(word)
    else:
        lowercase.append(word)
for word in sorted_list:
    print(word)
```

Comment: surely you either mean `capitalized.append` or `capitalized = set()`

Comment: Yes, sorry, my python is foggy, I am mostly a java programmer these days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
import re
import itertools

user_input = "Capitalized Get Listed words first"
splitwords = re.findall(r'''([A-Z][a-z]*)|([a-z]+)''', user_input)
words = [sorted([upper for upper,lower in splitwords if upper]),
         sorted([lower for upper,lower in splitwords if lower])]
# this is equivalent to:
#     caps, lower = zip(*splitwords)
#     words = [sorted(filter(None, caps)), sorted(filter(None, lower))]
# YMMV

for word in itertools.chain(*words):
    print(word)

## OUTPUT ##:
Capitalized
Get
Listed
first
words
```

Though it may be cleaner to simply split and find the index where the FIRST lowercase word occurs.

```
user_input = "Capitalized Get Listed words first"
sorted_input = sorted(user_input.split())
for idx, word in enumerate(sorted_input):
    if word.islower():
        capitalized = sorted_input[:idx]
        lowercase = sorted_input[idx:]
        words = capitalized + lowercase # concat lists
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

These approaches don't jumble up the order of the ouput.

**The input**

```
text_array = "Capitalized Words Get Listed first".split()
```

**Using a single for loop: ( Does not use sorted and hence does not jumble the order )**

```
upper = []
lower = []

for word in text_array:
    if word.istitle():
        upper.append(word)            
    else:
        lower.append(word)
```

**Using a single list comprehension:**

```
lower = list(text_array)
upper = [ lower.pop(lower.index(word)) for word in text_array if word.istitle() ]
```

**Using two separate list conprehensions:**

```
upper = [ word for word in text_array if word.istitle() ]
lower = [ word for word in text_array if not word.istitle() ]
```

**Using Nested list conprehensions:**

```
lower = []
upper = [ word for word in [ word if word.istitle() else lower.append(word) for word in text_array ] if word is not None ]
```

**Using two filters**

```
upper = filter(lambda word : word.istitle(), text_array)
lower = filter(lambda word : not word.istitle(), text_array)
```

**Using single filter:**

```
lower = []
upper = filter(lambda word : True if word.istitle() else bool(lower.append(word)), text_array)
```

**Printing the output using a single for loop:**

```
for word in upper + lower :
    print word
```